# Document sharing to other apps

Tags: ios, ios5, uidocumentinteraction

my app is document based,user can preview any type of file and can edit with other apps using open in option.if file is modified by other apps, how can get that modified file to my app? Is ios 4.2 later version having  any public shared directory for get updated document.Please help...